# number of free queries on google custom search

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

I am using google custom search for my site, I saw someday google custom search does not return anything while searching just advertisement. On googling I found that only 100 searches allowed per day as free searches. While reading the CSE documentation it does not say same for the free version. Can someone clarify on this in detail.

Comment: You would probably be better off using Adsense for search. You can set up site search with AFAIK any number of queries. You must run ads on the search results page, but you earn money from them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's true. You have only 100 free queries per day.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview